# Vuetify 3 v-radio-group set model to null

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I have some code that I am setting my Vuetify themes in its parent to pass down the name to the component and loop each of the color palates to create a "theme picker". What I then want to do is have a v-radio button next to the name of the chosen palate and when I click a different palate it should clear the radio button for the ones that are not chosen and instead set the model for the group to use the chosen to be null. This would be easy enough except that the component only has one group with one radio button. It just looks like there is a group because the parent component is looping through the available themes and displaying the component based on that.

Here is the component.

```
<template>
    <v-card
      max-width="400"
      class="mx-auto"
    >
       
      <v-container>
        <v-row dense>
          
          <v-col cols="12">
            <v-radio-group inline v-model="currentTheme">
            <v-radio 
            :label="props.themeName" 
            density="compact"
            :value="props.themeName"
            @click="toggleTheme(props.themeName)"
            >
            </v-radio>
            </v-radio-group>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="2">
            <v-sheet outlined color="background" rounded :theme="props.themeName"
            heme="props.themeName">
                <v-card
                    variant="outlined"
                    color="primary">
                    &nbsp;
                </v-card>
            </v-sheet>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="2">
            <v-sheet outlined color="surface" rounded :theme="props.themeName">
                <v-card
                    variant="outlined"
                    color="primary">
                    &nbsp;
                </v-card>
            </v-sheet>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="2">
            <v-sheet outlined color="primary" rounded :theme="props.themeName">
                <v-card
                    variant="outlined"
                    color="secondary">
                    &nbsp;
                </v-card>
            </v-sheet>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="2">
            <v-sheet outlined color="secondary" rounded :theme="props.themeName">
                <v-card
                    variant="outlined"
                    color="primary">
                    &nbsp;
                </v-card>
            </v-sheet>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="2">
            <v-sheet outlined color="error" rounded :theme="props.themeName">
                <v-card
                    variant="outlined"
                    color="secondary">
                    &nbsp;
                </v-card>
            </v-sheet>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="2">
            <v-sheet outlined color="info" rounded :theme="props.themeName">
                <v-card
                    variant="outlined"
                    color="secondary">
                    &nbsp;
                </v-card>
            </v-sheet>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="2">
            <v-sheet outlined color="success" rounded :theme="props.themeName">
                <v-card
                    variant="outlined"
                    color="secondary">
                    &nbsp;
                </v-card>
            </v-sheet>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="2">
            <v-sheet outlined color="warning" rounded :theme="props.themeName">
                <v-card
                    variant="outlined"
                    color="secondary">
                    &nbsp;
                </v-card>
            </v-sheet>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-card>
  </template>
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useTheme } from 'vuetify'
const props = defineProps({
  themeName: String
})
const vTheme = useTheme()
let currentTheme = vTheme.global.name.value


function toggleTheme(themeName : string){
 currentTheme = null;
 console.log(currentTheme, themeName) 
 vTheme.global.name.value = themeName 
} 
</script>
<style scoped>
 .input__details {
    display: none !important;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the `v-radio-group` outside of the component, so that it surrounds all of the individual theme pickers. The group is still associated with the nested radios through injected data. It would look something like this:

```html
  <v-radio-group v-model="currentTheme">
    <theme-radio-button
      v-for="themeName in themeNames"
      :themeName="themeName"
    />
  </v-radio-group>
```

You can bind it directly to `useTheme().global.name`:

```
  import { useTheme } from 'vuetify'
  const currentTheme = useTheme().global.name
```

Here it is in a [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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).

---

But if you prefer it, you can also do it without a surrounding v-radio group, but then you have to bind to `useTheme().global.name` directly, so that the radio can update the theme when it is clicked, but also reacts when a different theme is selected.

```html
<v-radio-group inline v-model="currentTheme">
  <v-radio
    :label="props.themeName"
    :value="props.themeName"
  />
</v-radio-group>
```

and as above:

```
const currentTheme = useTheme().global.name
```

Have a look at the [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Comment: That works. I was hoping to keep it all self-contained but this works.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, that's possible too, have a look at the updated answer

Comment: Just put [`hide-details`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-radio-group/#props-hide-details) on the v-radio-group